# How to get GPS data? emulator always returns runtime GPS disabled on Tizen native

Tags: gps, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

I am trying to access GPS data on Tizen native app. I have turned on location asked permissions, privileges, and granted permission on emulator. But when I run code to access location information, it gets zero values. For runtime location info it gets GPS Disabled equivalent return. I need to access current injected location on emulator.

Sample code to check GPS status:

```
retCheck = runtime_info_get_value_int(RUNTIME_INFO_KEY_GPS_STATUS,
        &value_int);
if (retCheck != RUNTIME_INFO_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "runtime_info_get_value_int error: %d",
            retCheck);

    snprintf(chars, sizeof(chars),
            "<br>runtime_info_get_value_int error: %d", retCheck);

    strcat(str, chars);
    return;
} else {
    switch (value_int) {
    case RUNTIME_INFO_GPS_STATUS_DISABLED:
        dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "GPS status: DISABLED.");
        snprintf(chars, sizeof(chars), "<br>GPS status: DISABLED.");
        strcat(str, chars);
        break;

    case RUNTIME_INFO_GPS_STATUS_SEARCHING:
        dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "GPS status: SEARCHING.");
        snprintf(chars, sizeof(chars), "<br>GPS status: SEARCHING.");
        strcat(str, chars);
        break;

    case RUNTIME_INFO_GPS_STATUS_CONNECTED:
        dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "GPS status: CONNECTED.");
        snprintf(chars, sizeof(chars), "<br>GPS status: CONNECTED.");
        strcat(str, chars);
        break;

    default:
        dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "GPS status: Unknown.");
        snprintf(chars, sizeof(chars), "<br>GPS status: Unknown.");
        strcat(str, chars);
        break;
    }
```

Here it is returning `Serarching`.

Sample code for gps location info:

```
//init location manager with gps type.

location_manager_get_location(gps, &altitude, &latitude, &longitude, &climb,
        &direction, &speed, &level, &horizontal, &vertical, &timestamp);

snprintf(chars, sizeof(chars),
        "<br>In GPS: altitude %f, latitude %f, longitude %f, climb %f, direction %f, speed %f, horizontal %f, vertical %f",
        altitude, latitude, longitude, climb, direction, speed, horizontal,
        vertical);
```

Here all values are 0.

What to do to get GPS data?

**Edit solution:** It has to retrieve information on location manager callback.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your GPS is enabled  (manually enable in emulator settings->Location->GPS).

May be this article will help you for more information on location https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/location-sensors/location

Check this Privilege too(http://tizen.org/privilege/location).

There seems to be problem in enabling GPS, we cannot get location values in GPS disabled state.

Comment: The question description mentions it has enabled GPS enabled and Privileges added. Your answer doesnot shade light on real problem, that is on the second part of the title. That was only part initially. That is - Emulator always returning disabled.